# MS Chart AxisX Labels Should Be Aligned Not Alternating

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

With the image here, I want my AxisX labels (Mar Apr May Jun ... Totals)  to be aligned altogether not alternating as shown.  What properties should I modify? Much appreciated if you could provide an answer asap.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering, I finally found a property that solved the problem above.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.WordWrap; 
//This is a style that automatically changes during runtime.
//I added another line for the font size, just to be sure.  Consider it optional.
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelAutoFitMinFontSize = 11;
```

[image]